# TTF font on web application to a stream

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a web application where I need to use a font for a text and show it on the web page. a barcode actually. 
So this font gets the barcode out of string. I did similar one on windows app like below

```
Dim exeCurrent As [Assembly] = [Assembly].GetExecutingAssembly()
  'Dim nameSpc As String = exeCurrent.GetName().Name.ToString()
  Dim nameSpc As String = Main.GetType.Namespace
  _pfc = New PrivateFontCollection
  Dim loadStream As Stream = exeCurrent.GetManifestResourceStream( _
      nameSpc & "." & fontName)
  Dim byteBuffer(CType(loadStream.Length, Integer)) As Byte

  loadStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, Int(CType(loadStream.Length, Integer)))

  Dim fontPtr As IntPtr = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal( _
      Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(Byte)) * _
      byteBuffer.Length)

  Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(byteBuffer, 0, fontPtr, byteBuffer.Length)

  _pfc.AddMemoryFont(fontPtr, byteBuffer.Length)

  Dim pcFonts As Int32 = 1
  AddFontMemResourceEx(fontPtr, byteBuffer.Length, 0, pcFonts)
```

This piece of code is taken from SO and code project. It does the job. But when it comes to web application, I am not sure how to do the same. My font file is stored in project applciation folders. 
Could someone help me getting this in web application

Answer (score 1):

So now that I did find my own solution. All we need is memory stream which will write the data to  marshal.alloccotaskmem(length). where length is the memory stream data.length

```
Dim data1 As Byte()
  Dim ms As New MemoryStream

  ' Using ms As New MemoryStream()
  Using file As New FileStream(strpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte(file.Length - 1) {}
    file.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(file.Length))
    ms.Write(bytes, 0, CInt(file.Length))
  End Using
  data1 = ms.ToArray()
```

This absolutely works with every font that I want to use as barcode and so is in my web application

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have the right to distribute the TTF file, you would use CSS to create a `@font-face` declaration. Then you can simply type your numbers and assign the barcode font via `font-family`:

[How do I use the webfonts? at Fontspring](https://www.fontspring.com/support/installing_webfonts/how-do-i-use-the-webfonts)

Answer (score -1):

If I understend correct you are asking about how to dynamically generate images on aspx.

Here is some example article that will explain.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx

Comment: Nope this is not what I am asking. I am asking for font to be loaded so that string will be converted to a barcode image.